# why didn't rishis write down vedic verses as and when they were revealed to them?

Tags: vedas

Considering that you do penance for tens, maybe even hundreds or thousands of year and then something is revealed to you, its infinitely precious.

why then would i not try to make sure to safeguard it ? the best way of safeguarding perhaps is penning it down somewhere safe , and then bind the pages in form of a granth.

rather we see the opp. the vedic verses were taught by the original seers onto their students in oral tradition, and those students then taught those onto their students and so on. 
But somewhere down the line perhaps there's a greater chance of missing out a laga-matra (matras of devanagari)  of pronounciation .

then it really puzzles me why they were not written down at the time of revelation.

maybe 2 reasons :

1) paper wasn't available. writing on palm leaves was tough as it decomposed too quickly

2) perhaps they feared denigration of the paper used for writing.

Comment: Why one write when one has photogenic memory? They would never forget anything once read or knew.

Comment: lets take one example. lets consider i teach you "the white bird sits on the tree". you teach it same to your students. a few generations down the line , someone out of mistake mutates it to "the white bird sits on the bee"
i hope u see what i am pointing to .
i am not doubting the vedic authenticity. all i am saying you can't guarantee in future students will have exact good memory as urs

Comment: having said this, i have to ask then why and when were vedas written down ? is it true that a kashmiri pandit thousand years ago decided to write it down to safeguard in the light of islamic invasions.

Comment: @Sikh and ye shall find it was allowed to give knowledge to everyone even a stranger:— https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21590/why-cant-sudras-read-vedas-according-to-smritis may be the writing was not developed or because it was listened (shruti) it was passed orally for a long time. :)

Comment: ohh. yes perhaps sanskrit was invented after vedas, not vice versa. But who wrote it down and what are the oldest manuscripts available to us ?

Comment: I personally feel Vedas were considered too too sacred to ever be reduced to paper or writing , which is destructible and subject to generation. I mean paper rots too . :(

Comment: @Sikh and ye shall find i don't know where the oldest manuscript is found but it was shruti (heard) all other epics are history(itihasa) and smritis and purans( that is old also smriti) may be i have a thing like purans were revised and and even converted like brahmanda purana was one vayu purana according to scholars but continues revesions converted it unlike vedas were on mouth means remembered, learned so nobody could interpolate them this was also a advantage that anybody could identify the addition to vedas.

Comment: Well one suggestion whenever you want to talk with someone put @ and his name otherwise he will not get your message. :)

Comment: Veda was revealed to rishis in a yuga (far away time) where humanity was very much improve than now, and inteligence was so subtle. They didn't really need to write, or even to make an effort to remember. After some time, in Dwapara yuga, mind start to become more dull, and they have need to rearrange and compile just some more essential parts of veda, and then Sri VedaVyasa compile on 4 vedas we know now (some say Atharva was compiled by others) just a little portion of it. After even more time, memory start to be really bad, and then wrtitings start to appear as a solution to that situation

Comment: The question is interesting @Sikhandyeshallfind