# What age should a Shudra do Upanayana?

Tags: caste-system, shudra, upanayanam

I'm reading the Wikipedia page of Upanayana,

> Many medieval era texts discuss Upanayana in the context of three of the four varnas (caste, class) — Brahmins, Kshatriyas and Vaishyas.The ceremony was typically performed at age eight among the Brahmins, at age 11 among the Kshatriyas, and age 12 among Vaishyas. Apastamba Gryha Sutra, in verse 1.1.1.27, places a maximum age limit of 24 for the Upanayana ceremony and start of formal education. However, Gautama Gryha Sutra and other ancient texts state that there is no age restriction and anyone of any age can undertake Upanayanam when they feel they initiate their formal studies of the Vedas.[16]
>
> Several texts such as Sushruta Sutrasthana, however, also include the fourth varna, the Sudras, entering schools and the formal education process,[17] stating that the Upanayana samskara was open to everyone.

As already said, some texts say Shudra should do Upanayana as well but what age should they?

Comment: If we go by Birth based system - no, Shudras are forbidden from Upanayanam. They don't have the "Vedic-adhikara". If we go by the guna-based system - why would a person with Shudra tendency will ever want to undergo a Upanayam? So, in both cases, answer turns out to be NO. Birth or guna based Shudra don't have adhikara to Upanayam.

Comment: @Vivikta - there is a 3rd case : someone born as shudra, but with brahmin guna. In case of this fancy new-age "guna-based" theory people seem to be fascinated about, he should also have upanayana at age 7 since he is "brahmin", right ? No. So the answer to this question can never start with "in case of guna-based", because there is no such thing. It is always birth-based, and it is only for dwijas. Of course, someone can take their next birth as dwija and then get upanayana. Laymen love to ignore the fact that karma & janma & jati are 100% meritocracy that spans across births.

Comment: As per scriptures like Manu Smriti, the various Puranas, Shudras are not qualified for Upanayana. Even Vidura (from Mahabharat), whom many people consider to be a man of great wisdom, did not have Upanayana as he was a Shudra.

Comment: This question cannot be answered since how can we know who is a Shudra or who is a Brahmana. So all people who want upanayana should get it at an appropriate age.

Comment: Good question, I didn't think of that how a person's caste could be determined at a such young age so they can get education later

Comment: Please provide a source for your claim of vedic adhikara @Vivikta

Comment: Well, I could write a detailed answer on  this which talk about "adhikara" from all the 18 major puranas, Smritis, and tantras /aagamas too. But, I don't see it worth the effort as of now.

Comment: *">since how can we know who is a Shudra or who is a Brahmana"* - so you're accepting that guna-based caste-system is a farce. good. Now if you say all who want it should get it, you are now stating the rules for a Vedic samskara. So you have to quote Shastras. You cannot just pick one part of a Samskara from scriptures and choose the other parts like when and who can do it, based on your personal opinions. So quote shastras that says shudras can get it done @PradipGangopadhyay

Comment: No, I am saying is the lineage based caste system is a farce. I consider the right place for all shastras that discriminate against people is the trash can.

Answer (score 4):

It is not mentioned in any scriptures because Shudras are not qualified for Upanayana as per Hindu scriptures.

> Manu Smriti 2.36. In the eighth year after conception, one should
> perform the initiation (upanayana) of a Brahmana, in the eleventh
> after conception (that) of a Kshatriya, but in the twelfth that of a
> Vaisya.

Nothing is mentioned about the Shudras in the above verse because they are not considered qualified for that Samskara.

Comment: Hmm I mean ManuSmirti is firsly a smirti and also a controversial text. The wikipedia states against what you said in first message.

Comment: I am not sure how Manu Smriti is a controversial text. Anyway it is the authority in Hinduism when it comes to deciding what is Dharma and what is not. Lastly, it's not only about Manu Smriti, there is not even a single Hindu scripture which says Shudras should undergo Upanayan@Buraian

Comment: @Buraian - if you already made up your mind to believe whatever wikipedia says, what is the point of asking on this forum?

Comment: Anyhow, I'll assume good faith: The question I asked in the post is fundamentally based on what is in the wikipedia, Rickross has given a smirti which says otherwise from it, but Manu is only one smirti and there are many other smirti works + some shruti one's which are conflicting to Manu's words. @mar

Comment: @Rickross How was it concluded that Manusmirti is the authority in Hinduism when identifying which is Dharma and which is not? To my understand it's a derivative work

Comment: Wikipedia for one gives " Sushruta Sutrasthana"

Comment: As I have said earlier, it's only about what Manu Smriti says. There does not exist any Smritis, any Puranas or any Tantras which say that a Shudra can undergo Upanayana. It was never practiced among Hindus too. I already gave an example from Mahabharat. Vidura was a Shudra, but he displayed great wisdom and other Brahmin like qualities. Yet he did not have the Upanayana because by birth he was a Shudra. So Shudras never used to wear the sacred thread in a Hindu society. But that said, i don't have any problems with your question too.@Buraian

Comment: @Buraian - in case you weren't aware of it already, wikipedia is generally an untrustworthy source. and when it comes to religion/politics, it is heavily left/atheist leaning, so we don't accept it's truthfulness when it comes to interpreting scriptures. all we do on this forum is try to quote Smritis/Puranas when possible since that's what we consider to be authority. It honestly sounds very funny to me that, people claim Smritis are interpolated and then point to Wikipedia as reference, whose whole existence is based on people interpolating it.

Comment: @Rickross Indeed Vidura has wisdom, but his nature was tamasic or static he was by his past deeds a Shudra and hence by his nature is aversed to learning preferring his life as it is. However, his wisdom could lead him to becoming a Brahmin after many other lives if he undergoes this nature.