# Are Some Of The Characteristics Of Kaliyug & Satyug Meant Figuratively

Tags: yuga, kali-yuga

Just wondering if is there is a figurative meaning of some of the characteristics described in Hindu texts for Kaliyug, Satyug ?

Any respected commentaries of our religious works touch on this ?

Like when it says the height of people will be so little in Kaliyug, is that figurative for morality of people being “little” or much less ?

Some of the characteristics described in Hindu texts for Kaliyug & Satyug seem so exaggerated that seems they must be meant figuratively. While others seem like descriptions meant to be taken literally.

Comment: [Here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7545/why-do-gaudiya-vaishnavas-think-the-order-of-the-yugas-is-satya-dwapara-treta) is a fun interpretation :) See [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/36764/is-every-yuga-linked-to-a-veda?rq=1) too

Comment: Thx @Rāmachandra 