# What are some vedic references about Kali-yuga

Tags: vedas, kali-yuga

What are some vedic references about Kali-yuga.

What do the Vedas say about Kali-yuga?

Comment: The Yugas are from the Puranas. They are not mentioned in the vedas.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/21553/22556 see this.

Comment: Scriptures like srimad Bhagavatam talk about Kali Yuga. It's exclusively spoken in the 12th canto of the canto Shrimad Bhagavatam. I'm not sure if Vedas giving detailed descriptions