# Signs of Kali Yuga

Tags: puranas, advaita, vaishnavism, kali-yuga, yuga

Just a question.

I have heard that an onset of certain things would indicate that Kali Yuga is getting increasing worse.

Just recently, I have seen a lot of friends and family get daughters rather than sons.

I see many families getting daughters in recent couple of years.

Then, when asking, I heard my mother say that in Kali Yuga, the number of girls will be more than boys. This is an indication that Kali Yuga is getting increasing worse.

Is this true that in Kali Yuga, girls will outnumber boys? If so, what's the logic/reason/rationale in Kali Yuga?

Are there any other such events that will indicate that Kali Yuga is getting very worse?

Comment: On the basis of whatever little knowledge of scriptures that have been obtained, it can be unhesitatingly stated that the concept of the girls outnumbering boys as a sign of Kaliyuga is most nonsensical & crappy theory that has been ever encountered till now.

Comment: There is no concept of *Yugas* in the Vedas/Upanishads. Puranas have reference to this Yugas for a special purpose that isn't meaningful to be taken literally.

Answer (score 1):

I have posted some verses about Kali Yuga in a Purana.

**Kali Yuga**

> These are the characteristics of Kaliyuga: violence, jealousy,
> falsehood, deception and slaughter of ascetics. These are the
> characteristics of Kali age which people inherit.

**Vayu Purana I.58.31**

> Affected by the traits of the Age, entire dharma deteriorates. It is
> doubtful whether the livelihood (of the people) can be achieved even
> by putting up mental strain, physical exertion or prayers.

**Vayu Purana I.58.32**

> In Kali Age, there are fatal diseases. There is perpetual fear of
> hunger. There is terrible danger of draught. Vision is blurred and
> rendered perverse.

**Vayu Purana I.58.33**

> In Kali age people are unrighteous, unmindful of the rules of conduct,
> fierce in anger but deficient in power and splendor. They always utter
> falsehood.

**Vayu Purana I.58.35**

I have not seen any mention of daughters being more than sons. What is the problem with women being more than men? Most societies in the world have more women than men.

Comment: Are there any Vedantic references to *Kali Yuga* too? Apart from Puranic references. I guess Kali Yuga was a puranic concept invented to characterize the time before righteousness was re-established after the concepts of dharma got corrupt. This fits the very logic - knowledge (truth) never gets destroyed but gets rediscovered each time again. This is my limited understanding from it.

Comment: @Abhas Yes. Kaliyuga is mentioned. Refer this thread: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/31624/647

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Please read the answer. The Taittiriya Samhita of Yajurveda is apparently something very different from what we are discussing. Immediately the next answer that follows the question explicitly states that through the quote of Swami Vivekananda Vedas has no Yuga division: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/21562/29449 . Tho, there is indeed the use of the word *Kaliyuga* but that's a different meaning apparently.